# How can I automate the process of connecting to a PC remotely through VNC?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, automation, vnc

I have an application that I wrote a few weeks ago that automatically connects to specific PCs on our network when you click the PC's name in the list. The process involves inputting the PC's name and a default password into VNC and pressing enter to connect. It runs perfectly on one PC, but is hit or miss on another. I'm sure I could redo the automation using a different method, but I liked how simple it was the way I had it, which is:

```
string x86Path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\uvnc bvba\\UltraVNC\\vncviewer.exe";

        try
        {
            startVNC.StartInfo.FileName = x86Path;
            if (startVNC.Start())
            {
                startVNC.WaitForInputIdle();
                SendKeys.Send(pcName);
                SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
                startVNC.WaitForInputIdle();
                SendKeys.Send("apassword");
                SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
            }
        }
```

When VNC starts, it waits for input (which will first be the PC name) and then sends the ENTER key. Then it waits again for input (this time it's apassword) and then sends the ENTER key. This will successfully connect to the PC 90% of the time. But sometimes it will hang and the password won't be submitted automatically. Is there a better way to do this? Is this a horribly incorrect way to implement WaitForInputIdle()?

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx
 on using catch clauses to deal with errors.

You could use something like a catch if password did not input or a catch that if still waiting enter password again. Any catch is good to have as long as its a predictable error. This could keep it simple.

you could also separate the 2  startVNC.WaitForInputIdle(); so that password input is based on if pc name input worked since its a bool you could use the first valid wait to start the next not as simple.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873(v=vs.110).aspx 
for Task.Delay Method.

If its a predictable amount of time you could also use a delay instead of wait. Say delay of (2000) is 2 seconds this is same size of code but not as simple because you'd still have original wait but also now instead of second wait you'd have a delay task. Hope this helps I am new to answering questions so I added reference to catch and delay instead of recommending direct changes.